# Can Google Data studio be able to connect to AWS RDS or Redshift currently?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-analytics, amazon-redshift, looker-studio

Maybe this really basic question, but I am trying to connect Data studio to AWS MySQL or with Redshift. I have found old posts where people say that is not possible.

But I am not sure if this is currently possible.

Comment: Please update your question - what have you tried? what errors do you get?

Comment: According to [this post](http://benswebsite.co.uk/connecting-google-data-studio-amazon-redshift/), connection should work straightforward as a *postgresql* source.  However, I get `Sorry, we encountered an error and were unable to complete your request.` and would thus be very interested in further description and solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to MySQL databases with the [Data Studio MySQL connector](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7088031?hl=en&ref_topic=7332343).

You can expose your Redshift data by using [JDBC driver](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html) or by deploying a [REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023578/rest-api-for-redshift). You can then build a [Data Studio Community Connector](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/get-started) to fetch data from either of these sources.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to connect Data Studio to Redshift with the Redshift connector (released December 2021). https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/11377200?hl=en

> The Amazon Redshift connector lets you create data sources based on Amazon Redshift. You can then visualize that data in your Data Studio reports and explorations.

You have two connection methods available:

- Connect with a hostname or IP address
- Connect with a JDBC URL: `jdbc:redshift://<hostname or IP address>[:<port>]/<database>`

Note it's a beta feature:

> This feature is in beta testing. You can expect this feature to change, and there may be some rough edges.

There are also some limitations:

> - You can query a maximum of 150K rows using this connector.
> - Column headers (field names) must use ASCII characters only. Non-ASCII characters aren't supported.